# SQL Query using DATE_ADD for time

Tags: php, date, get

Hey guys I've tried to figure this out,
I have

```
$query = "SELECT URL
          FROM Matches 
          WHERE match_date = '" . $currentdate . "'
          AND play_datetime < '" . $currenttime . "'
          AND DATE_ADD(play_datetime, INTERVAL 3 HOUR) > '" . $currenttime . "'";
```

I can get the first AND to return, but the second part wont work where i have DATE_ADD, ive tried it by itself to return anything and i cant get it to work!

$current time right now is 06:01:14, its = date(h:i:s);
then in play_datetime it picks up the match_date lists a result, the time in play_datetime is 04:00:00

Comment: What is the value of `$currenttime`?

Comment: FYI, you can combine them into `'$currenttime' BETWEEN play_datetime AND DATE_ADD(play_datetime, INTERVAL 3 HOUR)`

Comment: play_datetime is it an timestamp or an date  type?

Answer (score 0):

According to your query :
$currendate have date
and $currenttime have time.

But your column name "play_datetime" suggest that it is having datetime or timestamp .
so if this is right that your query is working  but you have to put $currentdatetime instead of $currenttime.

```
$query = "SELECT URL
  FROM Matches 
  WHERE match_date = '" . $currentdate . "'
  AND play_datetime < '" . <timestamp> . "'
  AND DATE_ADD(play_datetime, INTERVAL 3 HOUR) > '" . <timstamp> . "'";
```

Comment: I have $currenttime = date('h:i:s');   So does that mean <timestamp> can be $currenttime because it isnt returning me anything. In my DB play_datetime is type TIME.

Comment: i can return from play_datetime < '" . <timestamp> . "' just not the DATE_ADD

Comment: timestamp means date("d-m-Y h:i:s"); tell me datatype of play_datetime ? then i can tell you in better way.

Comment: Actually when you trying to add interval through DATE_ADD() function in column play_datetime which is having time then it returns null.as You can try "set @a=curtime();Select @a;select DATE_ADD(@a,Interval 1 Hour);".DATE_ADD() add interval in timestamp or datetime datatype check manual.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime

Comment: try ADDTIME(play_datetime,"3:0:0") instead of DATE_ADD(). It will work.